# Displaying variable goes wrong in IE , works in FF/Chrome etc

Tags: php, variables

So im trying to build me a website, using php mysql.
The following code produces a logo on the site.

```
<img src='assets/img/<?php echo $bedrijfslogo; ?>' alt='...' />
```

Where the $bedrijfslogo variable is filled earlier. i know the variable is filled and not null  because the logo renders in Chrome, but refuses to render in IE and FF , since there is no value.

When looking at the source in IE, i can see that the variable IS empty?

```
<img src="assets/img/" alt="..." />
```

When looking at the source in Chrome there IS a value...

```
<img src='assets/img/veey2.png' alt='...' />
```

WTF am i doing wrong here? :/

Comment: What is the value of `$bedrijfslogo`? `veey2.png`?

Comment: yes, so im totaly baffled why its there in Chrome but absent in FF and IE

Comment: also i just seen that the title is wrong, it only renders in Chrome....

Comment: Where does the value get set? I can only imagine something else is happening that's preventing the value being set. Maybe try echoing `$bedrijfslogo` somewhere in to the text of the page so you can see if its correct in all browsers?

Comment: Already tried this, the value is filled in Chrome and displays.

Comment: when echoing, the value , same as the logo , displays in Chrome, but not in FF/IE

Comment: please bare in mind, this is the testing fase so no pdo yet.    $dbQuery_form13 = "SELECT * "; 
$dbQuery_form13 .= "FROM users where email = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result_form13 = mysql_query($dbQuery_form13) or die("Couldn't get file list");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_form13))
{
$uid = $row["id"];

$club = $row["bedrijfsnaam"];
$bedrijfslogo = $row["bedrijfslogo"];
}

?>

Comment: If the value only exists in Chrome then something else must be happening in the PHP code. Are you doing and kind of browser detection? There is literally no reason a variable would exist in one browser but not the other unless it was programmed too. Can you add that code to your question? It's hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem at all.
If i had taken a minute and breath, i would have seen that the variable is filled based upon if your logged in or not, the difference was that in one browser i was logged in, and in the others i wasnt...... ASHAMED

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is a server-sided programming language it is in theory **impossible** to not see a variable in Internet Explorer and see it in Chrome.

I suspect you're HTML is incorrect and/or the filename contains an invalid character, something like:

```
<img src='assets/img/filename'.png' />
```

Notice the ' char.

It *can* be that the WebKit engine (Chrome) will render it anyway and the MSIE engine (Internet Explorer) won't.

--
Besides,  is the same as

Comment: No the filename is not incorrect as far as i can see ! the filename is stored in the db as VARCHAR, and gets pulled by mysql.

Comment: Do you have an online example? So we can get some more information.

Comment: and there is no extra ' anywhere

Comment: again even echoing the value doesnt work in IE and FF , in Chrome it renders Veey2.png withouth problems.

Comment: There is no extra ', no other errors as far as i can see. so im really baffled

Comment: ok, im going to stand in a corner, and be very very very ashamed.

Comment: i forgot i added a loggedin check..... omfg im so sorry to have bothered you guys

Comment: for some reason the value is empty when not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<img src='assets/img/<?=$bedrijfslogo?>' alt='...' />
```

let me know its helpfull or not?

Comment: Seeing as that's just shorthand for `<?php echo $bedrijfslogo; ?>` I doubt there'll be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

> Where the $bedrijfslogo variable is filled earlier.

Have you **checked** that it exists/has a value?

In the comments you said that you populate this variable in a select statement with `where email = '".$_SESSION['username']` - so if there's difference across browsers, I would assume that your session is simple not working, most likely because of the session id cookie not accepted by some browsers.

---

If the above is the case, PHP would have warned you already, if you only had set your error reporting to a sensible debugging value - so please do that *now*!